# Remove character at the end of url

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting

1) I have url like this :
http://example.com/post.php?id=1234
And inside : my article

2) but for this url 
http://example.com/post.php?1234somewords
It's also work, i see my article

3) and for this url
http://example.com/post.php?somewords
I have good 404 page error

Question is : how could i have 404 error for the 2) url ?
(alternative question : how could i redirect "1234somewords" to "1234" ?)

php mysql query inside post.php is :

```
require_once('conn_sql.php');
$post = $_GET['post'];
$nQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE post_id = '$post'");
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($nQuery);
```

It seems that the query "post=1234somewords" works, and this is not what i want.
however, if i search "post=1234somewords" in phpmyadmin, this not works, and this is what i want !

What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that your `post_id` field is an `INT` and so MySQL is type juggling *1234somewords* from a string, resulting in (int) *1234* which works.

Comment: As an aside - you're wide open to SQL injection attacks, you should update your code to use a prepared statement with bound parameters.

Comment: Check `$_GET` array for `id` ? and if it is not set return 404 ?

Comment: this happen because mysql  use the beginning part of the string as a  valid id ..  (this i related  to the implic data convdrion performed  by mysql) you should check if your parameter are valid number  before perform the query

Answer (score 1):

this happen because mysql use the beginning part of the string as a valid id .. (this i related to the implic data conversion performed by mysql) you should check if your parameter are valid number before perform the query

you could try removing the not numeric value from the string

```
$result  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $_GET['post']; );  

if (is_numeric( $result))  {

  $nQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE post_id = '$post'");
  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($nQuery);

} else {
  ......

}
```